# Объясните разницу между прибором и инструментом

Tags: семантика

Как отличить прибор от инструмента?  Приведите примеры, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Традиционно в русском языке под инструментом подразумевают предмет, используемый в процессе ручного труда, как правило, простой по своему устройству -- молоток, гаечный ключ и т. п. Развитие технологий добавило сюда и относительно сложные устройства, но по-прежнему предназначенные преимущественно для ручного труда -- электродрель, электрорубанок и прочее.

В промышленности инструментом называется та часть станка, которая непосредственно воздействует на обрабатывамую деталь или заготовку -- резец у токарного станка, фреза у фрезерного, сверло, буровой инструмент у буровой установки. Отсюда "инструментальный цех", "инструментальное производство", "твердосплавный инструмент", "алмазный инструмент".

В несколько переносном смысле словом "инструмент" также обозначают средство достижения какой-либо цели -- "Инструмент воздействия на общественное мнение".

См. напр. [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=Инструмент&all=x&bts=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82&all=x&bts=x)

Слово "прибор", как правило, используется для обозначения более сложных вещей, используемых в быту и в относительно "высокотехнологичных" видах деятельности -- напр. СВЧ-печь, вольтметр, осциллограф, бинокль. Бывают осветительные приборы, измерительные приборы, оптические приборы.

Словом "прибор" также называют активные элементы электронной техники -- транзисторы, электронные лампы, микросхемы. Бывают, например приборы с зарядовой связью (ПЗС-матрицы в фотоаппаратах), электровакуумные приборы (радиолампы и электронно-лучевые трубки) и так далее.

Кроме того, слово "прибор" традиционно используется для обозначения некоторых наборов предметов: "столовый прибор", "письменный прибор", хотя сейчас, кажется, такое использование этого слова становится довольно редким.

См. напр. [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=прибор&all=x&bts=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80&all=x&bts=x)

Путаница с этими понятиями возникает из-за неграмотного использования "ложного друга переводчика" -- английское слово `instrument`, кроме значения "инструмент", означает еще и "прибор", но не очень грамотные или не очень добросовестные переводчики зачастую во всех случаях переводят его  как "инструмент", не особо вникая в смысл переводимого текста. Известная компания "Texas Instruments", например, выпускает транзисторы, микросхемы и различное электронное оборудование, включая измерительные приборы, но отнюдь не молотки и не пилы.